# Execution plan quotes spill level 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, query-tuning

Running a very simple query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM WH.dbo.vw_data m
ORDER BY DateCompleted
```

Takes around 4 minutes.

96% of the execution is taken up by the following:

[image]

What does the warning mean and how is it interpretted?

The field `DateCompleted` isn't indexed: does this mean unless we hit an alternative field with an index, or add an index to `DateCompleted` it will always be slow?

Comment: As I can see, you are using the view? View can contain many JOINs. So your request can be executed for a long time.

Comment: Whoever down-voted please can you explain the problem with this question?

Comment: No worries - I've asked for a moderator to look as Darren Davies got down-voted as well - his answer seems like a good suggestion and no real reason why it should be down voted. You are correct I'm querying a view but if I switch to using the DateKey in the script then it runs very quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely index `DateCompleted`.  You can see from the execution plan that 96% of the cost occurs when sorting this field, therefore it makes sense to add an index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_DATE_COMPLETED
    ON YourTable (DateCompleted);
```

Answer (score 6):

> Sort Warnings are raised by SQL Server when a sort operation cannot be done in memory and must spill to tempdb

This article answers your question on Sort Warnings (link updated again, thanks to @quarkonium:

http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/identifying-solving-sort-warnings-problems-sql-server/

Comment: +1 excellent reference (hoping to get some training with those guys some time in the future)

Comment: Frankly I think this is the real answer to the question but alas it seems the URL has changed over time. The info is now hosted here: http://www.solidq.com/identifying-solving-sort-warnings-problems-sql-server/

Comment: Moved again: http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/identifying-solving-sort-warnings-problems-sql-server/